# Ubuntu 18.04 password

Tags: 18.04, password, login-screen

I am running long running matlab code on Ubuntu 18.04.
Can I do something that requires a password so that there is no user login while the analyzes are being made on the computer ?

So when I'm not at the computer, I don't want anyone else to tamper with the computer.

But matlab should keep working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you want to do is lock the screen. Most desktops have an entry for that in their menus, usually near the logout / shutdown entries. I don't have an 18.04 machine any more so I can't be more precise about where it is.

See also https://vitux.com/three-ways-to-lock-your-ubuntu-screen/